# undefined reference to symbol 'gluLookAt'

Tags: opengl, gcc, fedora

I'm using Fedora 16. I've installed freeglut and freeglut-devel packages. I tried to rum a simple opengl program, but i'm getting the following error

```
gcc cube.c -o cube -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSFol4w.o: undefined reference to symbol 'gluLookAt'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'gluLookAt' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libGLU.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: why someone is always so mean by downing a question that he is either not interested or unable to answer? This question help me solve a similar question. This question and the asker should be respected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link some gl libraries.

```
g++ cube.c -o cube -I /usr/lib/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 -lGL
```

Answer (score 7):

Compile :     `g++ sampleCode.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU`

run      :     `./a.out`

is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consult some introduction text on compilers, linkers and libraries, i.e. how the pieces come together when building a program. In essence the linker is telling you, that there are some loose ends and it cannot finish linking the program due to them. Adding a library happens by the -l switch with library name (GLU in your case), not by giving it a full path to the library file.

Answer (score 1):

do what it says

```
gcc cube.c -o cube -lglut -lGLU
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got the following errors.                               /tmp/ccYMzpUF.o: In Function 'drawbox' :                              cube.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to 'glBegin'                 like this it lists all functions starting with gl..

Comment: Then add -lGL too. You really should read something about the linker.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Undefined reference to glBegin.

Comment: That command misses the linkage to GL itself. The command should read `gcc -o cube cube.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut`

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS when I wrote:

```
g++ square.cpp -lglut
```

But then I found on the web that some people also added -lGL and lGLU so I did it and it compiles now:

```
g++ square.cpp -lglut -lGL -GLU
```

Comment: What does the `gut` library do?

Comment: Sorry it should of course be -lglut instead of -lgut. It is a OpenGL library that is needed, you could read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit